# I added a SECRET_KEY config variable to my Django app on Heroku but now it won't work locally

Tags: python, django, heroku, environment-variables

I changed my secret key to an environment variable on my Heroku app. I changed it because I found out that keeping the secret key in `settings.py` was a security risk.

However, now it won't work locally when I use `python manage.py runserver`. It gives an error about the secret key.

How do I fix it so I can develop my Heroku app locally?

Comment: Having a different SECRET_KEY in production and on your local machine shouldn't be a problem.
What doesn't work? Can you be more precise? Do you get any specific error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export your secret key as an environment variable locally.

```
export SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey
./manage.py runserver
```

Or you could change your `settings.py` to use a hardcoded secret key in DEBUG mode. If you do this, make sure you are running with `DEBUG = False` on Heroku.

```
import os

if DEBUG:
    SECRET_KEY = 'mysecretkey'
else:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

Comment: I tried what you have exacly the way you have it  it gave me an error until I did this 'from django.conf import settings' then when I ran it again it said the following  'The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.'

Comment: Sorry, it should be `if DEBUG`, not `if settings.DEBUG`. Make sure the if statement comes after the `DEBUG = ` line in your settings.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your environmental variables in your development environment.

**Windows**

Go to Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings.
Go to the *Advanced* tab, and at the bottom there is an *Environment Variables...* button.

In there you can edit the variables as you like.

**Linux**

Edit `/etc/environment` to include:

```
SECRET_KEY = <yoursecretkey>
```

or

You should be using a virtual environment to isolate your system Python installation from your different projects (it solves conflicting version requirements) and to make deployment easier. [Virtualenv Tutorial](http://www.simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/)

To activate your virtual environment when you want to use it there is a shell script located at `<your_virtualenv>/bin/activate` that handles changing all the environmental variables that make the virtual environment work.

Add:

```
SECRET_KEY='<yoursecretkey>'
export SECRET_KEY
```

to the bottom of the `activate` file and when it is run it will add (`export`) the environmental variable.

Comment: I'm not that advanced. I am self taught. i do not know how to export things the way you describe unless I have more directions

Comment: @nothingness do you use Windows or Linux?

Comment: Im on a mac @JamesFenwick

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of trouble working this out too, found my answer here: [Set up your local environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables)

If you are using heroku local to develop locally, this might work for you. I just needed to include this line in an .env file placed in the top directory with my Procfile:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'yourkey'
```

And in settings.py:

```
os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

This works great for me. Otherwise if for whatever reason you aren't using heroku local, maybe you could try importing your key from another file when working locally (and placing this file in your gitignore), and swapping back to the heroku config variable for deployment.