# I tried adding secret_key environment cariable to my bottom of bin/activate but it didn't work

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables, local

I tried adding secret_key environment cariable to my bottom of bin/activate file but it didn't work. This advice was given to me on another post. At the bottom of my activate file I added this

```
SECRET_KEY_LO = 'i+acxn5(akgsncjwbckbkwbcsciscnclnwoc9r9ejrn;of=s'
export SECRET_KEY_LO
```

Then i restarted my my server but it did not work. How Can I make this work. I'm quite sure that I'm missing something but I don't know what. Heres the advice I was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302869/i-added-a-secret-key-config-variable-to-my-django-app-on-heroku-but-now-it-wont)

Answer (score 0):

I just finished this for my project if your doing this locally with your virtualenv, you can add the following to your bin/activate : 
`export SOME_SECRET_KEY='1248FHAAK-this-is-secret-key2849'`

I see that you also have heroku as a tag for your question, with heroku you will need to set the environment variable with the following:
 `heroku config:set SOME_SECRET_KEY=1248FHAAK-this-is-secret-key2849`