# KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY' django migrate?

Tags: python, django

```html
  File "/home/user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/instagram_miner/ig_miner/settings.py", line 23, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

I put a secret key but appears this error

KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

this is my code of secrets.sh

export SECRET_KEY='key '

```html
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

export SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey

please help me

Comment: Please add more information. this happened after a succesful migrate or during it?. Post your `settings.py` and the server's output when you try to run your app. PS: be careful with sensible data and remove your SECRET_KEY from this thread

Comment: i put more information

Comment: i solve something whit this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302869/i-added-a-secret-key-config-variable-to-my-django-app-on-heroku-but-now-it-wont but not solve all problem

Comment: i solve the problem now thanks for your help

Comment: good for you!, can you post the solution and explain how you solved it? PS: please mark this thread as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey
./manage.py runserver

this solve my question thanks